# Angularjs perform translation on a template loaded dynamically with JSON data

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, translation, i18next, angular-translate

I am building an app which needs translation

My app structure is something similar to this

someDirective.js  -----> load someDirective template

someDirective template - <p>{{data.name}}</p>

So my question is, whether it is possible to perform translation on the template?

something like <p>{{data.name | translate}}</p>

If so, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using i18ng, which wraps i18next. I highly recommend it, and it does exactly what you want and more. Apparently ng-i18next does about the same, but I haven't tried it.